# mod rewrite ignores digits in condition, how to make it take digits into account?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, webserver

All is done inside httpd.conf, there is no .htaccess

I have two simple conditions. If url has in it the string "talis" direct to one file, otherwise to another.

```
RewriteRule talis talis.php [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

**This piece works as expected**
[domain]/t/1/talis/s  goes to talis.php
[domain]/t/1/bob/s  goes to index.php

But when I try to put numbers in there, it always defaults to the last rule

```
RewriteRule talis01 talis.php [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

(notice talis**01**)

This will always go to the second condition.
[domain]/t/1/talis01/s  goes to **index.php**
[domain]/t/1/bob/s  goes to index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a relative *substitution* string then I assume these are in a *directory* context (perhaps `.htaccess`), as opposed to a *server* (or *virtualhost*) context. And the dot in the second rule's *pattern* is also intended for a *directory* context.

mod_rewrite isn't "ignoring the digits". The request is rewritten to `talis.php` by the first rule, but then `talis.php` is being rewritten by the second rule to `index.php`.

In more detail...

> ```
> RewriteRule talis talis.php [L]
> RewriteRule . index.php [L]
> ```

In the first example, a request that contains `talis` is rewritten to `talis.php` and the `L` flag causes the rewrite engine to start over. On the second pass `talis.php` also matches the same rule and is rewritten to `talis.php` again. Since the URL is unchanged, processing stops and `talis.php` accepts the request.

If it was not for the fact that the first rule also matches `talis.php` (the URL that the first rule rewrites to) then this too would result in the request being rewritten to `index.php`.

> ```
> RewriteRule talis01 talis.php [L]
> RewriteRule . index.php [L]
> ```

In the second example, a request that contains `talis01` is first rewritten to `talis.php` and the `L` flag causes the rewrite engine to start over. `talis.php` does not match the first rule, but it does match the second rule so the request is rewritten a second time to `index.php`. The `L` flag causes the rewrite engine to start over. The second rule matches (again), the URL is unchanged so processing stops and `index.php` accepts the request.

Assuming you are on Apache 2.4 then the easiest solution is to use the `END` flag on the first rule, instead of `L`. This stops all processing by the rewrite engine and prevents another loop.

For example:

```
RewriteRule talis01 talis.php [END]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Although, ordinarily you would use a more restrictive regex and/or *conditions* to ensure that rewritten requests are not rematched by any of the directives (if that is not the intention). eg. It is unusual to see the second rule without any *conditions* since this literally rewrites *everything* to `index.php`, including requests to `index.php` itself.

Comment: Few comments: 1. [L] is equal to "break" i.e. if the rule is matched, the engine stops right there and ignores what comes after. 2. the rule ```RewriteRule talis talis.php`` means "If there is anywhere in the url the pattern talis, redirect the request to talis.php"

Comment: The first one, with just talis works as I explained, the second one, where all I did was adding 01 to the pattern, is not working.

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka Yes, as I've explained in my answer. But the `L` (`last`) flag does not stop all processing when used in a _directory_ context. It stops the _current round_ of processing only (yes, the directives that follow are not processed in the "current pass") but the rewrite engine starts again... the resulting URL (ie. now `talis.php`) is remapped to the filesystem and the directives in the current context are reprocessed. Even the first rule isn't doing quite what you are expecting (it is processed twice), but yes, the net result is that `talis.php` is served.

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka Did you try the `END` flag instead of `L` in the penultimate rule (or even both rules for that matter)?

Comment: If I put end it wont get the default behavior I want (anything else to index.php) or did u mean this as a debugging step?

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka To clarify, are these directives in `.htaccess`, or a `<Directory>` container in the server config?

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka "If I put end it wont get the default behavior" - Yes it will, at least according to the expectation as described in the question. The `END` flag only applies if that rule is successful (just like the `L` flag). When the URL contains `talis01` it is rewritten to `talis.php` (finish), everything else is rewritten to `index.php`, since "everything else" does not match `talis01`.

Comment: Now I got it :-D tnx!